# Calling individual items with "this" term

Tags: jquery, html, this

I'm making a webshop for school (so it's not a functional one). On my products page i have 7 items, when you hover over 1 of them, it should expand.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gsno2.jpg

But when i hover over one of them, the obviously all open. I'm quite new at this Jquery thing but i know you can call only 1 of the items with the "this" term.
I searched all of the internet but somehow i can't seem to find a solution that works.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add your code to your question.  Not pictures of your code

Comment: There are no `this` in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't use the $('.Slidebox'), it will get you all elements having class .Slidebox Try below code.

```
$('.Item').hover(function(e){
   $(this).find('.Slidebox').slidedown(1000);
}, function(e){
   $(this).find('.Slidebox').slideup(1000);
);
```